# Java: New Line after 18 Chars & new Array Index after 13 Lines

Tags: java, arrays

I am pretty new to Java and I have a little problem with formatting a String. I have add "\n" for a new line after every 18th char and I have to split these new lines into array indexes, 13 lines for each index.

My code so far:

```
String[] strings = str.split("\n");
String result;
for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; i++) {
    i++;
    if ((i % 13) == 0) {
        result += strings[i];
    } else {
        result += strings[i] + "\n";
    }
}
```

It doesn't work as it should, I tested a bit around bit I don't know how to do this, could someone help me please?

Comment: Try using with `\\n` and see if it works..

Comment: To me, the obvious problem would be that you have `i++` twice in the loop.  Try removing the `i++;` that's at the top of the loop.  Also, I think you want `i` to start from 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` twice in each loop - once in the increment expression of the `for` statement, and once inside the loop itself. This means `i` is always even, so `i % 13` is probably not 0 when you expect it to be. In addition, the first index of an array is 0, so you would currently ignore the first element. As a more minor point, I would advise using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of appending `Strings`:

```
String[] strings = str.split("\n");
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    String s = strings[i];
    if ((i % 13) == 0) {
        resultBuilder.append(s);
    } else {
        resultBuilder.append(s).append("\n");
    }
}
String result = resultBuilder.toString();
```